# T-SQL How can I get the most common value from a result set

Tags: sql-server-2012

Trying to get a single result for the most common date in a result set :

```
SELECT col1, col2,  
(SELECT MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,[date], 103)) FROM TABLE )  AS [Date]
FROM TABLE WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160131'
```

Results :

[image]

So I just want `15/01/2016`. I know I need to use a subquery and a count for this and have tried many different solutions, being a newbie I'm finding subqueries harder to get my head around than `JOIN`s especially correlated nested subqueries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by `date`, order by `count descending` and select `top 1`:

```
select top 1 with ties [date] 
from table 
where [date] between '20160101' and '20160131'
group by [date]
order by count(*) desc
```

`with ties` will select multiple dates if max count can be the same for some dates.